# Perl exited with active threads:

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl

I have a Perl program. Everything is working fine, but I am seeing the errors below. I have also joined threads in the end, and tried checking `is_joinable`, but nothing is working. This error is not causing any issue at the moment but I want to fix it

```
Perl exited with active threads:
        6 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

#### code

```
my @threads;
open FILE, "$inputCsv" or die $!;
my @records = <FILE>;

foreach $record ( @records ) {
    @fields = split( /,/, $record );
    $identityDomain = $fields[0];
    push( @threads, threads->new( \&populateSubscriptionMap, $identityDomain ) );
}

foreach $thr ( @threads ) {
    print "threads - " . $thr;
    my %myhash = $thr->join();
}
```

I have spent almost 3 hours on this and tried various things. I would appreciate if someone can take a look and help me out.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this problem in a test script. Is this the only place you're creating threads, or have you left something else out?

Comment: Yes this is the only place .

Comment: can you copy paste the script that is working fine for you ?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, I get `No such file or directory at a.pl line 2.` when I run your code. Please provide an actual demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Answer (score 4):

```
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

is a simple way of waiting for all threads to end, but your problem is far more likely to be that you don't actually reach the part of your code that reaps the threads. The most likely culprits are:

- Your main thread threw an uncaught exception.
- Your main thread or one of the other threads used `exit`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked once of my functions have exit in it.